# How to position a data table inside a DIV element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I am using the below code to generate a table during run time using bootstrap and datatable plugin.Data table is created as expected,however i am unable to position this table inside the div and control the pagination.

Can some one help me to correct the code so that data table will be created relative to the div element.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/jquery-
 3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/jTable/media   /css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/jTable/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/jTable/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/jTable/media/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tblorderbody').DataTable();    
  } );   
 </script>

 </head>
<body>  
<div class="bodyContiner">      
    <div class="runStatus">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="cellspacing:0;display: block; position: relative;" id="tblorderbody">
          <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:10%;">CASE ID</th>
                <th style="width:25%;">SCENARIO TYPE</th>
                <th style="width:10%;">ORDER START TIME</th>
                <th style="width:10%;">PROCESS MODE</th>
                <th style="width:10%;">AGENT NAME</th>
                <th style="width:30%;">COMMENTS</th>
                <th style="width:5%;">STATUS</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id ="tblordertbody">             
            </tbody>                                
        </table>
        <script>displayTablebody();</script>
    </div>
</div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: First of all - you shouldn't use same Ids for <table> and <tbody> tags.
And please show the displayTablebody function code.

Comment: can you make a fiddle of your code

Comment: can you also give a screenshot what is exactly happened on your problem?